# How can I search for specific siblings in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nodes, siblings

I have nodes like

```
<Level1 id="11">
  <Level2 id="1111">
    <Level3 type="UserID" id="111111">12345
    </Level3>
    <Level3 type="UserID" id="111112">23456
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
  <Level2 id="1112">
    <Level3 type="Username" id="111211">John
    </Level3>
    <Level3 type="Username" id="111212">Paul
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
  <Level2 id="1113">
    <Level3 type="Street" id="111311">Westminster Rd.
    </Level3>
    <Level3 type="Street" id="111312">Long Rd.
    </Level3>
 </Level2>
</Level1>
```

and want to get a list like

```
<personlist>
  <person>
    <name>12345</name>
    <name>John</name>
    <name>Westminster Rd.</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>23456</name>
    <name>Paul</name>
    <name>Long Rd.</name>
  </person>
</personlist>
```

The first node of UserID always corresponds to the first node of Name and Street, second node of ID to second node of name and street and so on.

So I know that I could go into each Level3 node of type "UserID" and get the position.
But somehow this doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Level3[@type='UserID']">
  <xsl:variable name="pos">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
  </xsl:variable>                
  <xsl:value-of select="..//Level3[$pos]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But somehow I only get 12345 as result...

Answer (score 0):

The XML you're working with is constructed strangely for this sort of result, but what your current XPath is doing is only getting you `<Level3>` nodes that have a type = UserID, then getting their position and redundantly getting the same data again with that index. Since there's only 2 nodes from your targeting XPath, you'll only get back the results for those indices which is why you see `12345` each time.

Try using something like `<xsl:for-each select="//Level3">` which will get you a list of all of the Level3 data you're attempting to retrieve, then format it via xslt. Since your ids don't match per line, you'll have to go by position and hope your assumption that they correspond holds true.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the expression

```
..//Level3[$pos]
```

you go only one level up the tree to the `Level2` element. You should go up two levels to the `Level1` element:

```
../../Level2/Level3[$pos]
```

Another problem is that the way you calculate the position of a `Level3` element is wrong. The expression

```
position()
```

returns the position in the node-set you're iterating over, not the position inside the parent element. You'll need something like:

```
count(preceding-sibling::Level3) + 1
```

Then you should make sure that you evaluate this expression in the `select` attribute of `xsl:variable`. If you use `xsl:value-of`, the result will be a string which won't do what you expect when you use it as an index later.

Summing up, something like the following should work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Level3[@type='UserID']">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(preceding-sibling::Level3) + 1"/>
  <person>
    <xsl:for-each select="../../Level2/Level3[$pos]">
      <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </name>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </person>
</xsl:for-each>
```